# how to query the child object record's from Parent?

Tags: soql, query

I have a Object called 'Vehicle', and I have lookup field for the Object called "Unitorder" in Vechicle.
In unitorder i have a lookup field for the Object called "carset"
In carset I have related list object called "service".

I want to take the Service records.

Am able to take upto carset.

Query:

```
[Select name,UnitOrder__r.Carset__r.name from Vechicle]
```

How to take the related service records for Carset in a single query ?

Carset is master and service is child object.

Comment: Say the Relationship in manner of "What is Parent and What are Childs"? Your description is confusing. Don't tell the Names of the lookup fields. Just say what are your parent and child objects and From which object you want to query from?

Answer (score 2):

You need to form two separate SOQL queries for that. One to query Carset and service child records, like below

```
SELECT Name, 
      (SELECT Name FROM Service__r)
FROM Carset
```

and other one same as you have mentioned in your question. You can use both of them to form a map or wrapper class to achieve what you have mentioned. I don't think you can achieve this task using a **single** soql.

Check out [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html) blog to get a basic understanding of Parent-child and Child-parent SOQL.

Comment: There is no relation ship between Vechicle and carset

Comment: Do you want to query both Vehicle and Service in single query?

Comment: Yes.There is no relationship between vechicle and carset. to obtain carset from vechicle am going via "unitorder" .Now i want to get related list of service from carset in "single query"

Comment: I want to get the service from vechicle

Comment: What is the relationship b/w Service and Vehicle, I can't derive any relationship b/w them, from your question or comments.

Comment: What I have understood from your question is 
Carset is Parent, UnitOrder is Child of Carset, Vehicle is child of UnitOrder
& Service is child of Carset. 
Correct me if I have got this wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40969/discussion-between-uma451-and-mahmood).